# How should page-specific styling be applied to BEM blocks?

Tags: css, sass, bem

Suppose we have a block element named `.button` which we want to reuse **with different margin** values on multiple different pages.

**Possible solutions:**

```
//1. Nested styles 
.page-1 {
    .button { margin: 10px; }
}

.page-2 {
    .button { margin: 20px; }
}

//2. Specific modifier for EACH page
.button {
    &--pg-1-margin { margin: 10px; }
    &--pg-2-margin { margin: 20px; }
}

// 3. Special, page-specific block level element
// which will be COMBINED with an existing block-level 
// element (ex: <button class="button page-1-element">...</button>)
.page-1-element { margin: 10px; }
.page-2-element { margin: 20px; }
```

1. Which one of these will be considered BEM-friendly way?
2. Is the first method acceptable / preferred way if there are **too many** different margins used?

Comment: "page-specific" "reusable" Pick one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer to your question in official docs: https://en.bem.info/methodology/css/#external-geometry-and-positioning

Comment: Thanks! I should've missed that one somehow